# Using File in Java

Tags: java, image, file, illegalargumentexception

I want to use File class for using a image which is in my resources folder.

```
new File(String.valueOf(this.getClass().getResource("Cards/Blue/1.png")));
```

I tried, but to console throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided file does not exist!
```

Thats my resources folder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87G2e.png)

Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: To use a resource you use getResource, or getResource as stream. You don't use a `File` class object.

Comment: [ImageIO.read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) works with either an input stream or a url. Which also happens to be what you get from 'getResource'.

Comment: What's the point of the `String.valueOf` in there? Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: Why do you need a `File` object? The purpose of that class is really to act upon paths in a file system. If you need to use an image then you need a `URL` or `InputStream` so you only need what's already at the heart of your own code

Comment: See link - you're looking for the `MyClass.class.getResource` variant, which you can directly pass to `ImageIO`, `new ImageIcon`, etc.